# I need a regex to parse a FTP URL

Tags: php, regex

can someone help me construct an preg_match pattern to match this data?

I have data like this

```
ftp://username:password@server <br>
ftp://username:password@server <br>
ftp://username:password@server <br>
```

ect

i would like an preg_match to match each line as an variable, and use that in an foreach loop

thanks

Comment: What's the problem with splitting on lines?  What do you want regex for?  If you are trying to get the components of the URL, check out `parse_url()`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

in simple case it is... but you should check rfcs to see what characters allowed or not allowed in such URLS.

```
<?php

$lines=explode("\n","ftp://username:password@server <br>
ftp://username:password@server <br>
tp://username:password@server <br>
ftp://username:password@server <br>");

foreach ($lines as $line) {
if (preg_match('/^ftp:\/\/[\da-z]+:[^\@]+\@[^\s]+ <br>\s*$/',$line)) {echo "$line is ok\n";}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you dont need preg_match. You can use explode. Make sure to use array_pop after explode to eliminate the last empty key.

```
<?php
$linkArray = explode(" <br>",$links);
array_pop($linkArray);
?>
```

Now each value of the array will contain the link but not "br" tag. I think that should do.

Is your data in the below way ?

```
$str=    "ftp://username:password@server <br>
          ftp://username:password@server <br>
          ftp://username:password@server <br>";
```

If yes, my solution will work.

Comment: no, explode just gives me back the whole string, i need to divide the string into array variables

Comment: All the three url lines are in one string ?

Comment: `list($var1,$var2,$var3) = explode(...)` ?